# Varying a group of drop down boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I want a search page with five fields from the MYSQL database shown in individual drop down boxes. I have a basic drop down, adapted from one of the other answers here which I have reproduced five times for each of the fields.

```
$sql = "SELECT Country FROM engravers";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name\\='Country'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['Country'] . "'>" . $row['Country'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Repeating with obvious changes gives me five neat little drop down boxes that all work.

I want all of the boxes to be interactive so each box will have a default of "all" unless clicked. That means a user could click on a country and a year and get only the records that fit both criteria.

I want a single submit button to handle them all.

Comment: How big is this database? Were there ever more than a couple of thousand engravers?

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer something like this... http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#combination-filters

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

```
echo "<select name='Country'>";
echo "<option value=''>All</option>";
```

To get the submit button to submit all of them, just put them all in the same form.

(How you handle the `''` option in the search depends on the code that processes the form data)